# AWS Terraform Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid availability zone [eu-south-1a]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

First of all, i converted all aws resources to terraform files with terraformer tool. (on us-east-1) Then, for testing i choose new region (eu-south-1) on aws and when i run terraform apply it says **Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid availability zone: [eu-south-1a]
│       status code: 400**

How can i fix this?

Conf. file:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tfer--i-0f541036d004e944c_rancher-dev" {
  ami                         = "ami-04505e74c0741db8d"
  associate_public_ip_address = "false"
  availability_zone           = "eu-south-1a"

  .....
```

I research but didnt find anything.

Comment: Can you try adding the AZ as "eu-south-1" instead of "eu-south-1a"?

Comment: It's same. 
Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid availability zone: [eu-south-1]

Comment: What is in your provider config block?

Comment: provider "aws" {}

terraform {
 required_providers {
  aws = {
     version = "~> 4.37.0"
  }
  }
}

Comment: Set the region in the provider block to `eu-south-1`. It's probably using `us-east-1` as a default region. So that would be `provider "aws" { region = "eu-south-1" }`

Comment: It is worked thank u for support

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following block to your aws_instance tf resource:

`metadata_options { http_endpoint = "enabled" }`